# Ember.js create bound input for every property of an object

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

So, what I want to achieve is to create a form where the user can enter localized names for input fields. Let's say I have a object like this one:

```
var field = {
    fieldName: {
        de_DE: 'German field name',
        fr_FR: 'French field name',
        en_US: 'English field name'
    }
}
```

And I have the list of available locales:

```
var locales = ['de_DE', 'fr_FR', 'en_US'];
```

And now I want to create a bound input field for every locale:

```
{{#each locales}}
    {{input value=fieldName.get(this)}}
{{/each}}
```

Is there a way to do this in Ember? The list of available locales is dynamic so I can't hardcode the fields for every locale.

Comment: I was able to achieve something like this because I built a set of custom form components that needed to be dynamically passed their bound value.  At the end of the day it works like this. Here's my template: `{{input value=view.fieldValue}}`. Then in my view, I can dynamically assign `fieldValue` to whatever I want. You may want to use the controller instead of the view.  Not sure if this will work for you, but hopefully it's a direction to look in.

Comment: This would work if I wanted to bind the localized value for only one certain locale. In this case I want to create three bound field, each for every available locale.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, not sure. Maybe you could load the locales as a property in your controller `locales` and then also create individual properties that are named according to your locale. Then in handlebars, try `{{#each locales}} {{input valueBinding="locales.myFieldName"}}`.  I predict 50/50 chance of success with that.

Comment: Not shure how this would work. Can you give me an example?